# .htacces folder hiding from URL

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've had a page running Wordpress.
All the content are in a folder, so when I open the page, I see the folder name in the url:
example.com/new/gallery

Is it possible to hide the "new/" from the URL?

I've got 2 .htaccess file, one in the root:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    new/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) new/$1    [L]
 </IfModule>
```

And one in the "new" folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on

    # Ebben az alkonyvtarban vagyunk, ezt
    # figyelembe kell venni az atirasoknal
    #RewriteBase /cegunkwebhelye

    # Minden nemletezo oldal webcimet iranyitsuk at az index.php-re
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [QSA]
</IfModule>

DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
# BEGIN WordPress

# END WordPress
```

Pls, help me! Thanks!

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=.htacces+folder+hideing+from+URL+-+Stack+Overflow

Answer (score 1):

Take Back Up of your word press database and logging to admin panel.

1) Go to settings >> general

remove /new/ from

```
Site Address (URL) :
```

2)Copy index.php and .htaccess from 'new' folder and paste it outside of new folder.

3)Edit index.php from

```
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

to

```
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/new/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

and check example.com 'your primary domain'. it will load website without 'new' from URL.